# Globalization and localization in dotnet core web api 3.1 using VSCode

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnetcorecli

I want to add **Globalization and localization in dotnet core web api,** although I tried with the following link. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1

, however, I didn't succeed.

Here is my Startup.cs code...

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources/Localization");
services.AddControllers() 
.AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix, options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Resources/Localization"; })
.AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

 services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => 
 {
     var cultures = new []
     {
         new CultureInfo("en"),
         new CultureInfo("fa")
     };
     options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
     options.SupportedCultures = cultures;
     options.SupportedUICultures = cultures;
 });
```

Configure method contains the following

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, Seed seeder)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        } 

        // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        //ADDING LOCATIONLIZATION
        app.UseRequestLocalization(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

Here is the Resources/Localization folder structure with .resx files.

[image]

Finally, when I build the dotnet api with the **dotnet build** command it provides the following error in ***Visual Studio Code*** Terminal.

> /Users/naimdahee/Desktop/ERPEra/ERPEra.API/Resources/Localization/ERPEra.en.resx
>   : error MSB3103: Invalid Resx file. System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   [/Users/naimdahee/Desktop/ERPEra/ERPEra.API/ERPEra.API.csproj]
>   /Users/naimdahee/Desktop/ERPEra/ERPEra.API/Resources/Localization/ERPEra.en.resx
>   : error MSB3103:    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResourceHandling.MSBuildResXReader.ReadResources(Stream
>   s, String filename, Boolean pathsRelativeToBasePath)
>   [/Users/naimdahee/Desktop/ERPEra/ERPEra.API/ERPEra.API.csproj]
>   /Users/naimdahee/Desktop/ERPEra/ERPEra.API/Resources/Localization/ERPEra.fa.resx
>   : error MSB3103: Invalid Resx file. System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   [/Users/naimdahee/Desktop/ERPEra/ERPEra.API/ERPEra.API.csproj]
>   /Users/naimdahee/Desktop/ERPEra/ERPEra.API/Resources/Localization/ERPEra.fa.resx
>   : error MSB3103:    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResourceHandling.MSBuildResXReader.ReadResources(Stream
>   s, String filename, Boolean pathsRelativeToBasePath)
>   [/Users/naimdahee/Desktop/ERPEra/ERPEra.API/ERPEra.API.csproj]
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> /Users/naimdahee/Desktop/ERPEra/ERPEra.API/Resources/Localization/ERPEra.en.resx
>   : error MSB3103: Invalid Resx file. System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   [/Users/naimdahee/Desktop/ERPEra/ERPEra.API/ERPEra.API.csproj]
>   /Users/naimdahee/Desktop/ERPEra/ERPEra.API/Resources/Localization/ERPEra.en.resx
>   : error MSB3103:    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResourceHandling.MSBuildResXReader.ReadResources(Stream
>   s, String filename, Boolean pathsRelativeToBasePath)
>   [/Users/naimdahee/Desktop/ERPEra/ERPEra.API/ERPEra.API.csproj]
>   /Users/naimdahee/Desktop/ERPEra/ERPEra.API/Resources/Localization/ERPEra.fa.resx
>   : error MSB3103: Invalid Resx file. System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   [/Users/naimdahee/Desktop/ERPEra/ERPEra.API/ERPEra.API.csproj]
>   /Users/naimdahee/Desktop/ERPEra/ERPEra.API/Resources/Localization/ERPEra.fa.resx
>   : error MSB3103:    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResourceHandling.MSBuildResXReader.ReadResources(Stream
>   s, String filename, Boolean pathsRelativeToBasePath)
>   [/Users/naimdahee/Desktop/ERPEra/ERPEra.API/ERPEra.API.csproj]
>       0 Warning(s)
>       2 Error(s)

Comment: How do you add resource files?could you run in the visual stuidio?

Comment: Just by right clicking I added these two resx files, however they doesn't contain any data. On the other hand, I dont have Visual Studio installed. I only utilize VS Code.

Comment: As far as I know,you could not create resx file directy using vs code.Since resx file is just a xml file , so either download visual studio or manually write the xml into your created file.The xml looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928486/use-same-resx-file-in-asp-net-core-and-net-core-console-project

Comment: I want to cling with VSCode and as I am an Android App developer I dont have any problem writing the xml code manually. I will try, lets see what happens. I really want to express my gradtitude for your time and assistance. Thanks alot.